# Error while choosing Pypy as Jupyter notebook kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pypy

I'm trying to use Pypy3 as a Jupyter notebook kernel but facing an error when selecting the kernel.

Working on Windows 10.

I installed Pypy 3.7 v7.3.4, added Scripts directory to PATH and did:

```
pypy3 -m ensure pip
pypy3 -m pip install ipykernel
pypy3 -m ipykernel install --user --name pypy3 --display-name "PyPy3"
```

I can see the kernel when typing `jupyter kernelspec list`, and the kernel.json points to pypy3.exe.

When choosing the kernel I get the following error:

```py
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\zmq\sugar\attrsettr.py", line 51,
> in __getattr__
>     return self._get_attr_opt(upper_key, opt)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\zmq\sugar\attrsettr.py", line 63,
> in _get_attr_opt
>     return self.get(opt)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\socket.py", line
> 222, in get
>     C.zmq_getsockopt, self._zmq_socket, option, c_value_pointer, c_sizet_pointer   File
> "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\utils.py", line
> 74, in _retry_sys_call
>     _check_rc(rc)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\zmq\error.py", line 155, in
> _check_rc
>     raise ZMQError(errno) zmq.error.ZMQError: Invalid argument
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\plop1\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196,
> in _run_module_as_main
>     "__main__", mod_spec)   File "C:\Users\plop1\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85,
> in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16,
> in <module>
>     app.launch_new_instance()   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 844, in launch_instance
>     app.initialize(argv)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 87, in inner
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 567,
> in initialize
>     self.init_sockets()   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 292,
> in init_sockets
>     self.init_iopub(context)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 300,
> in init_iopub
>     self.iopub_thread = IOPubThread(self.iopub_socket, pipe=True)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line
> 66, in __init__
>     self._setup_pipe_in()   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 139,
> in _setup_pipe_in
>     self._pipe_in = ZMQStream(pipe_in, self.io_loop)   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line
> 103, in __init__
>     self._fd = self.socket.FD   File "C:\Users\plop1\PyPy3\site-packages\zmq\sugar\attrsettr.py", line 57,
> in __getattr__
>     raise AttributeError("{} attribute is write-only".format(key)) AttributeError: FD attribute is write-only
```

I tried without virtualenv, with pypy3 virtualenv, no luck...

Python version is 3.8.5.

Any hint ?

Comment: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/1533

Comment: Thank you @mattip

Comment: Could you try with the recent 7.3.5 bugfix release?

Comment: It seems like I can now start a Pypy3 kernel on jupyter notebook. That being said, I can't get the Pypy speed on "complex" calculation like

```python
import time

start_time = time.time()


total = 0

for i in range(1, 10000):

    for j in range(1, 10000):

        total += i + j


print(f"The result is {total}")


end_time = time.time()

print(f"It took {end_time-start_time:.2f} seconds to compute")
```
in the notebook.  It works well when I execute the same code in a python file in command line tho

Comment: The formatting is messed up, but what happens if you move the print outside the timing code. Printing in a notebook might take longer than the loop

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, didn't manage to put it well and cannot edit anymore it seems :(
I deleted every print and only left the code, the cell ran in 17sec. 
It took 0.14 sec in powershell launching pypy3 file.py

Comment: Please file an issue at https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues so we can address this properly